# Sql queries in c# student attendance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have one table which has 6 columns id, Username, status,remarks, date, role and I need to make a custom api through which I need to find the number of days a student is present between two dates.

Status is present/absent
Role is teacher/Student

I have tried to passed id, start date , end date to my router like
HttpGet["{Id}/{startdate}/{enddate}"]
But I can't pass date as this start and end date data type

How should I write the methods in controller?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: Whenever you are tempted to say `I got an error`, assume our next two statements will be "please show us the code" and "what was the error?".

Comment: Put the code in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the controller route contains only entities and the filters to be query parameters...

```
[HttpGet("{studentId}/attendance")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNumberOfDaysPresentAsync(
    int studentId,
    string dateFrom,
    string dateTo
)
{
    // Convert date string to date objects for filtering (if you want)
    var dateFromFilter = DateTime.ParseExact(dateFrom, "MM-dd-yyyy");
    var dateToFilter = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTo, "MM-dd-yyyy");

    // Now query your data...
}
```

You can perform the API request as such:
GET https://localhost/api/students/{studentId}/attendance?dateFrom=01-01-2020&dateTo=06-01-2020